# MVC Client side validation doesnt work when bootstrap collapse is applied

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, validation, asp.net-mvc-5

I have created a MVC 5 view with large number of fields, client side validation was working fine until I applied bootstrap collapse.

The client side validation works on expanded panel while the fields in the collpased panel doesnt validate on submit.

Comment: Some code would help...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

jQuery.validate by default doesn't validate any field with the attribute :hidden

If you want to validate your hidden controls, you will need to change the ignore setting.

IIRC

```
$.validator.defaults.ignore = "input[type=hidden]";
```

This will still ignore any hidden fields, but validate any input/select/textarea fields that are currently not displayed.

You may need to reload the forms validate settings for it to take effect, give it a try and see if it works

Comment: I tried it inside the $(function(){}) and it didnt work. Should i be doing it somewhere else?

Answer (score 1):

Set validator ignore setting as below. Anyway this will not expand the accordion sections but prevents submit.

```
 $(document).ready(function () {

        $.validator.defaults.ignore = "input[type=hidden]";
        });
```